# How to make a tree structure with v-for using parentid and order

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, v-for

I try to make a structure looking like this

[image: treefolder]

from the following state:

```
state: {
        appbar: [{
                name: "Section 1", // Name of element
                order: 1, //Define order, not used yet
                parentid: null, //Define if it has a parent null = no parent
                id: 1,
                type: "section", // Tell which kind of element
                icon: "#icon-menu" // Element icon
            },
            {
                name: "Section 2",
                order: 2,
                parentid: null,
                id: 2,
                type: "section",
                icon: "#icon-menu"
            }, {
                name: "Section 3",
                order: 3,
                parentid: null,
                id: 3,
                type: "section",
                icon: "#icon-menu"
            },
            {
                name: "custom-text",
                order: 1,
                parentid: 2,
                id: 4,
                type: "string",
                text: "Dummy header",
                icon: null //Can be null if no icon wanted
            },
            {
                name: "Chatroom 1",
                order: 2,
                parentid: 2,
                id: 5,
                type: "instance",
                instanceLink: "/", //Point to instance
                icon: null
            },
            {
                name: "Chatroom 2",
                order: 3,
                parentid: 2,
                id: 5,
                type: "instance",
                instanceLink: "/", //Point to instance
                icon: null
            }
        ]
    }
```

My component is as follow:

```
<template>
  <nav class="appbar">
   <div v-for="(item, index) in appbar.appbar" :key="index" class="appbar__section">
      <template v-if="item.type === 'section'">
        <button class="appbar__header">
          <div class="appbar__header-left">
            <svg class="appbar__header-icon" v-if="item.icon !== null">
              <use v-bind="{'xlink:href': spritePath + item.icon}"></use>
            </svg>
            <div class="appbar__header-title">{{item.name}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="appbar__header-right">
            <svg class="appbar__header-arrow">
              <use xlink:href="@/assets/icons/sprite.svg#icon-chevron-down"></use>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </button>
      </template>
      <template v-else-if="item.type === 'string'">
        <button class="appbar__header">
          <div class="appbar__header-left">
            <svg class="appbar__header-icon" v-if="item.icon !== null">
              <use v-bind="{'xlink:href': spritePath + item.icon}"></use>
            </svg>
            <div class="appbar__header-title">{{item.text}}</div>
          </div>
        </button>
      </template>
      <template v-else-if="item.type === 'instance'">
        <button class="appbar__header">
          <div class="appbar__header-left">
            <svg class="appbar__header-icon" v-if="item.icon !== null">
              <use v-bind="{'xlink:href': spritePath + item.icon}"></use>
            </svg>
            <div class="appbar__header-title">{{item.name}}</div>
          </div>
        </button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import spritePath from "@/assets/icons/sprite.svg";

export default {
  name: "Appbar",
  data() {
    return {
      spritePath
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["appbar"])
  }
};
</script>
```

I tried to use v-if to print different type of elements (section, chatroom etc) but it follows the order of the template.

The v-for should print each "parentid: null" as parent and all child elements pointing to "parentid: x" below, by also respecting the order number.

The goal is later to provide some methods (or mutations) to add or delete elements from this menu.

How could i possibly do that ? Is it by writting getters ? 
Any advice or example are very welcome.

Comment: where is your app code ... you just mentioned the `store` data... you have to show your attempts atleast

Comment: @Dadboz sorry ! I just added the template, as it's surely not the way it should be done i thought it was not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if you want full control over your tree view try this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html

if not then you can use any plugins which are easier to use than above method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tree-list